# R raster::extract function not working as expected

Tags: r, gis, raster, r-raster, r-sf

I'm trying to do some polygon/raster work in R. The extract function isn't working as I'd expect. Here's a reproducible example.

```
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(maptools)

raster      <-     download.file('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JimShady/london_osm_canyons/master/test.tif', 'downloaded_raster')
raster      <- raster('test.tif')

polygons    <- read_sf('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JimShady/london_osm_canyons/master/test2.geojson')
polygons    <- st_transform(polygons, crs(raster)@projargs)
polygons$id <- 1
polygons    <- as(polygons, 'Spatial')

new_polygon <- elide(polygons, rotate=-50)
proj4string(new_polygon) <- crs(raster)@projargs

polygons    <- rbind(polygons, new_polygon)

plot(raster)
plot(polygons, add=T)
```

[image]

I want to get the number of cells that the each polygon intersects with, even if they are NA, and store them in the polygon as a column

```
polygons$cell_count     <- extract(raster, polygons, fun = function(x,...)length(x), na.rm=F)
```

But this returns the number 5 for polygon one, when clearly the polygon intersects more than 5 cells of the raster. **What's going on with that?**

I then want to get the weighted mean. if there are any NA cells intersected, then this should 'fail' and return NA. **I think this works, but as the above is wrong, I'm not very confident of my method now.**

```
polygons$mean           <- round(extract(raster, polygons, fun = mean, weights=T, na.rm=F),2)
```

**I also want to know the number of cells that intersect that are less than one.** I'm not sure how to do that. Anyone got a good idea?

```
polygons$almost_zero    <-
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am getting a number of errors running your above code. Make sure that codes are easily reproducible.

Comment: Sorry I thought it worked. I'll fix it now.

Comment: Should be working now @SamAct

Answer (score 2):

From `extract` help:

> A cell is covered if its center is inside the polygon (but see the
>   weights option for considering partly covered cells; and argument
>   small for getting values for small polygons anyway).

Therefore, you could use this to have the number of cells:

```
data <- extract(raster, polygons,  weights = T,  na.rm = F)[[1]]
nrow(data)

#[1] 18
```

Where `data` is:

```
      value      weight
 [1,]     8 0.003610108
 [2,]     6 0.025270758
 [3,]     0 0.010830325
 [4,]     7 0.104693141
 [5,]     0 0.066787004
 [6,]     0 0.088447653
 [7,]     0 0.001805054
 [8,]     0 0.104693141
 [9,]     0 0.010830325
[10,]     0 0.093862816
[11,]     0 0.030685921
[12,]     0 0.063176895
[13,]     0 0.057761733
[14,]     0 0.063176895
[15,]     7 0.003610108
[16,]     7 0.102888087
[17,]     0 0.093862816
[18,]     0 0.074007220
```

To have the number of cells that intersects and are less than 1:

```
sum(data[, 1] < 1)

#[1] 13
```

---

**EDIT**

In case of several polygons, you should first dissolve your polygons using `rgeos::gUnaryUnion`:

```
library(rgeos)

polygons$id <- 1
polygons <- gUnaryUnion(polygons, id = polygons$id)
# As suggested by @RobertHijmans, you can also use `raster::aggregate`
# polygons <- raster::aggregate(polygons, by = "id")

plot(raster)
plot(polygons, add = T)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks DJack. Though how would I go about this if there were more than one polygon? I have edited my question to reflect this situation. I think perhaps I need to use some sort of lapply but I'm struggling with it. Thanks.

Comment: @TheRealJimShady you should not really edit a question in a way that makes an existing answer no longer correct.  If you have further follow up questions, you should post them as new questions (or in a comment if they are either trivial, or are just clarification of the current answer)

Comment: @TheRealJimShady I made an edit. But dww is right, next time, you should post a new question if you have further follow-up questions.

Comment: Cheers and noted

Comment: To "dissolve" it is more convenient to use `aggregate` as it keeps attributes

Answer (score 1):

Extract is behaving as it is meant to, by finding cells where the centroid lies within the polygon.  One way to deal with partial coverage is to convert your polygon to a raster mask, using `rasterize`. Note that in the following I renamed your raster and polygon r1, and p1, respectively. Because its not good practice to use function names for objects:

```
r_mask = rasterize(p1, r1, getCover=TRUE)
r_mask[r_mask==0] = NA
```

Now we can use this mask to get the values you want:

```
r2 = mask(r1, r_mask)
cellStats(!is.na(r2), sum)
# [1] 18
cellStats(r2, mean)
# [1] 1.944444
```

To find how many cells are less than one, we can do

```
cellStats(r2<1, sum)
# [1] 13
```